# Cannot see my chromecast in Guest Mode

Tags: android, google-cast

I have created a sample Android application just to see the "Google Cast" button on Action Bar and a list of ChromeCast devices when I press it. I did everything according to "Android Sender App Development" document. Now I do see my ChromeCast device when we are on same WiFi, but if I switch on my phone to another WIFi, I don't see my ChromeCast as a "nearby device". I did turned on a flag "Supports Google Cast Guest Mode" on "Google Cast SDK Developer console" for my application. What I am missing?
Here is the code in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
        .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(MY_APP_ID))
        .build();   
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
    mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY); 
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (isFinishing()) 
        mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cast, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Have you turned on the guest mode from your Chromecast Application as described in this doc: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6109286?hl=en

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, I can see ChromeCast in guest mode from YouTube application on same phone.

Comment: Can you try CastVideos-android sample app?

Comment: Ok. I downloaded and compiled the app, and I do see the cast button on guest mode. Still I cannot see what is different. They use "CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN" instead of "CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY", but it does not work for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the guest mode only works if the application is published.

I published my app (code above) and it started to show the ChromeCast button in both WiFi and guest mode.

Comment: with Guest mode, can you connect straight form the Sender application, or do you need to connect to the Chromecast device first, with the official Chromecast application?

Comment: I can connect straight from the Sender Application.